# Broken images on iphone

Tags: images, iphone

I have broken images on iPhone, it happens only on the home page where I added new images about a week ago (the new images are exactly the same format and more or less the same size as the old images)

this is the site: cartoonmaster.co.il

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You either upload or convert your images after upload to **webp** format, which is supported by limited range of browsers (see https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp for complete list). The important information for you is that it's **not supported in iOS Safari**

I suggest you re-upload your media in other image format (jpeg, png etc.). If you want to swap one for one for example from Media tab of your admin area, you could try plugin such as [Enable Media Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/)